# get the token from wkwebview after login in ios swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am loading a url in wkwebview for login. After successful login it will redirect it to inner page, from there when click a button it will redirect to another page where token is generated. After token is generated how to push that to swift application. I need to take that token for further use in my app. Please help with a complete solution

This is my code

```
 override func loadView() 
{
        super.loadView()
        
        let url = URL(string: "urlString")
        let request = URLRequest(url:url!)
        
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        
        webView?.load(request)
        
        self.view.addSubview(webView!)
        

    }
```

How to proceed further to get the token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add message name in your user content controller in your config

```
config.userContentController.add(self, name: "setToken")
```

add following extenstion in your view controller

```
extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
                               didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if (message.name == "setToken"){
            if let token = message.body as? String{
                print(token)
            }

        }
        print("Received message from native: \(message)")
    }
}
```

pass your token from js

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.setToken.postMessage(TOKEN_STRING);
```

Comment: Is this best practice and secure to pass the authToken in the JavaScript?